# Action bar in android pre-3.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been searching for a good example of ActionBar in pre-3.0 devices but I haven't found anything.

Are there any libraries for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use ActionBarSherlock library:

http://actionbarsherlock.com

It comes with a lot of examples so you can get a quick overview about the possibilities of that library. Moreover, it supports also fragments which I found to be very useful.

Comment: the only problem is that when I try to add it to eclipse, it fails in compilation... Which version should be targetted?

Comment: From the FAQ: The library itself must be built against Android 3.2 (API level 13). Your project should be built using the latest version of the SDK as possible (it is best to try and use the same version as the library). This is not a requirement, however, and you may build against any version of the SDK that is Android 3.0 (API level 11) or newer.

Comment: But if I build it for Android 3.2 any project that uses it won't be able to use it if it's under 3.2. Am I right?

Comment: No, you can set the minSdkVersion all the way down to 4 (Android 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

try the greendroid (http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/) library.

Comment: Greendroid library is quite good, but ActionBarSherlock is much more powerful, mature, and comes with much more examples.